# Newbie APIGee Question Regarding APIGee Proxy for an External Vendor

Tags: apigee

Got a bit of a newbie question - as I'm fairly new to the APIGee space (and proxies in general).  I have a requirement where I need to "frontend" an external service endpoint.   At a high-level, I have an internal (i.e. company network ) application that needs to call through a proxy to this third-party service.  Conceptually, I think APIGee could be used for this but I'm struggling with the "order" of operations.

Would it be something like this?

Interal API Process calls the APIGee Proxy Endpoint ---->
APIGee would calls/routes to the "Target Endpoint" (i.e. external services URL)

Obviously this is super high-level and basic, I'm really just looking for someone to confirm / or shoot down my understanding here.

Additionally if there is some document that I'm missing please share, I am interested in trying to learn for myself here as well.

I have reviewed the APIGee documentation provided [here](https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/fundamentals/understanding-apis-and-api-proxies).  Which helps, but I'd like to understand if the order of "operations" described above is correct.

Comment: I can't comment on whether this is a industry wide practice, but the order you've described is exactly how we have it in our company. Basically, all requests entering/leaving our company network happens via Apigee gateway.

Comment: Thank you @Ram for the comments.  With my limited knowledge, it would seem logical.

Answer (score 0):

You are accurately describing what I would call an *outbound*, or “inside-out” proxy. Apigee is, in my opinion, a bit more optimized for providing proxy services for external clients calling *into* your company, but it can be pressed into duty for use cases in either direction. Your case is legitimate, and you described the order of operations correctly. And the benefit of such an outbound proxy is that you can more easily report on usage and even control access to and/or meter consumption of your third-party dependency.